# How check punycode url?

Tags: php, punycode

How i can check in php, in what format displayed url
xn--d1acufc5f.xn--p1ai or домены.рф

I try use `$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']` but browsers where supporting  punycode, http_host return no encoding version

Comment: *"in what format displayed url"* – what does that mean? Your server will always see the punycoded version, because that *is* the actual URL, and the browser may or may not display it nicely, you simply have no idea.

Comment: @deceze And my question is how check  browser display it nicel or not

Answer (score 2):

You simply won't have any idea how the browser displays a punycoded URL. It is entirely up to the browser, there is no information communicated between the browser and your server that would enable PHP to know this.

Comment: But may be in js?

Comment: Not that I know, no.